# Komodo Edit: GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion `sys_page_size == 0' failed

Tags: command-line, glib

when i try to run Komodo Edit 8.0 from terminal, it returns me this error:

```
(process:9508): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion `sys_page_size == 0' failed
```

how can i fix this?

note: nevertheless, the application lauches and runs properly.

Comment: I believe you can ignore that error, I get that with almost any process that uses the GUI or GLib when I launch it from the command line.  That or similar errors.

Comment: As long as the process still runs and works, those are more or less irrelevant bits of data, but don't quote me on that one, I'm not entirely certain

Comment: It's an assertion - that's not really an error. It does say that something is different than expected inside the program, but it's not saying that it is a problem.

Answer (score 4):

This is being tracked on the Mozilla bug tracker at

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=833117

At the moment there is no fix, but the error/warning can be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

The assertion is informing you that the system it is running on has NO 
virtual memory meaning that there can be no "Page swapping", this is
unusual but not an actual error in itself although it is very likely to lead to a system crash or system freeze if ANY virtual swap memory is needed. This is a problem for just about everything that runs on this system, it is not an email related error at all, however the mail subsystem just happens to be one of the few things that reports it.

Solution: Set the amount of vrtual memory on this system to something other than zero,lol.

Comment: I added a swapfile but this error still occurs.  Does it have to be enabled at boot time to make the errors stop?