# Firefox won't start, 'sys_page_size == 0' error

Tags: 14.04, firefox, browser

Out of the blue, Firefox Developer Edition from the PPA on Ubuntu 12.04 wouldn't start. It did not launch by searching through Unity and clicking on Firefox. Typing `firefox` in terminal gave me the following error.

```
(process:9814): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed
```

I read [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/322702/komodo-edit-glib-critical-g-slice-set-config-assertion-sys-page-size-0) which has the same error message as me, but in their case it was a different program, and it ran normally.

Thinking it might be a problem in the Mozilla PPA build, I downloaded the .tar.bz2 and attempted to run firefox, but I got the same error.

**What is this error message? How can I resolve it and get Firefox Developer Edition to run again on Ubuntu 12.04?**